# Alternative to manual "SET NAMES utf8" on every database call

Tags: php, mysql

I have Japanese on my site coming from a mysql database.

Other Japanese text on the site displays fine, but the stuff coming out of the database looks like:

```
 ????????
```

The database is set to UTF8, so is the web page.

To fix the issue, before I make any calls to the database I use:

```
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

I was wondering if there was a better/easier way to do the above without having to set names before every query?

Comment: So, `SET NAMES utf8` fixes the issue or not? (All decent DB libraries allow to set client encoding, check the documentation for yours.)

Comment: Set set names does fix the issue, i was just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You only need that once per connection, not before every query. Also, if you use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), you can configure it so that it does that automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `SET NAMES utf8` before every query, you just have to run it once the connection is established. Here's an example with PDO :

```
try {
    $dns  = "mysql:host={HOST};dbname={DB}";
    $user = "{USER}";
    $pass = "{PASS}";
    $con = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Connexion error ", $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$con->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
//and now, as many queries as you want
```

If you're using PHP >= 5.3.6, you can define the charset in the connection string (prior PHP versions ignore it) :

```
try {
    $dns  = "mysql:host={HOST};dbname={DB};charset=utf8";
    $user = "{USER}";
    $pass = "{PASS}";
    $con = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Connexion error ", $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

//and now, as many queries as you want
```

Comment: But I have many database connections in different models, if you dont call set names before each one it doesnt work.

Comment: PDO provides a better way to set encoding. And we don't really know if he's using PDO or not: he hasn't said it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Right, I added the connection string way in my post.

Comment: @user1013512 You should centralize all those connections in a single one, to avoid this kind of problem.